# Django 2fa registration form

Tags: python, django, two-factor-authentication

I'm trying to make my own 2fa implementation for my project. I found [this](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth) library. They have [this example](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth/tree/master/example), i'm studying it in order to understand how it all works.

I'm now running the example using `py -3.7 manage.py runserver`, but i'm having some trobules understanding the following:

1) I would like to add an email address to the registration form, where do i edit the form? I tried to open the `views.py` file but there is nothing there.

2) How do i edit the login form? I would like to add captcha to the form, but still, there is nothing in the `views` file

Comment: There are views in the example you linked to

Comment: Yes but there isn't a login view there. I would expect to see an if statement etc. with the authentication

Comment: There's the `OTPRequiredMixin`

Comment: Got it. Thank you!